# working with access database update statment not working

Tags: c#, oledb

```
string date=
DateTime.Now.ToString("d.M.yyyy",System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);

String MyString = @"UPDATE cas SET Odhod= '" + label1.Text + "' 
WHERE sifra = " + textBox1.Text + " and Datum = "+date+"";
```

When I do thise update without Datum it works, but with Datum doesn't work. I'm connected to accesss database, and Datum field type in table is date/time Guys please help.

**Hire is the program:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/hx4zduvul8mh2uy/8.4.zip

**Pictre of problem:** http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/5189/errorbh.jpg

Comment: should the query string be like :
String MyString = @"UPDATE cas SET Odhod= '" + label1.Text + "' 
WHERE sifra = '"+ textBox1.Text + "' and Datum = '"+date+"'"; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, using string concatenation brings in a lot of trouble.
(Sql Injection, Parsing problems)

Just use parametrized queries

```
string MyString = @"UPDATE cas SET Odhod= ? WHERE sifra = ? and Datum = ?"; 


using(OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(MyString, cn)
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", label1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", textbox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Convert.ToDate(date));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Of course, the Date value stored in the Datum field should be exactly like the date passed in parameter @p3. Sometime it is good to add also the time value to your date

```
string date= DateTime.Now.ToString("d.M.yyyy 00:00:00", ......);
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hx4zduvul8mh2uy/8.4.zip
Thise is the full program, can you please make tat update work?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the value in your Datum column doesn't match your date value. What are the values of your Datum column? Is there some time associated with it (EG: 1:32pm)?

There are also a couple of other issues with this update statement. You should be either using an ORM or parameterized queries in order to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter approach. In that case, you will be able to define the field type before you run the query.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the way Microsoft Access actually reads the `DateTime` a particular way.  When you utilized concatenation it can introduce problems.

*Access* can only store *Date / Time* in these manners:

- Valid Date: -657, 434 (January 1, 100 A.D.) to 2,958,465 (December 31, 9999 A.D.)
- Valid Time: .0 (00:00:00) to .99999 (23:59:59)

It can be formatted in the following way:

- Stored Value (Double Number) = Default Format (General Date) = Custom Format
- 36296.0 = 5/15/99 = 05/15/1999 12:00:00 AM

So you'll have to keep in mind the limitations of Microsoft Access; because SQL does read the dates slightly differently and can store them slightly different.  The slightest break in context can deeply affect the outcome.

The easiest approach would be to *Query based on Parameters*.  That way you don't concatenate invalid syntax for Access possibly.  This will alleviate some of the issues.

Natively access utilizes these functions:

> Add an associated date to the time comparison:

```
var1 = #1/1/99 2:01:00 PM#
var2 = DateAdd("n", 10, var1)
? var2 = #1/1/99 2:11:00 PM#

Convert the time values to string data types before you compare them:

var1 = #2:01:00 PM#
var2 = DateAdd("n", 10, var1)
? CStr(var2) = CStr(#2:11:00 PM#)
```

> Use the DateDiff() function to compare precise units such as seconds:

```
var1 = #2:01:00 PM#
var2 = DateAdd("n", 10, var1)
? DateDiff("s", var2, #2:11:00 PM#) = 0
```

So a native *Access Query* would look like such:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Customer]
SET [dbo].[Customer].[InvoiceDate] = #1/1/99 2:11:00 PM#;
```

As you can see it tries to work like SQL, but it isn't SQL.  So by creating a **Parameter based Query you can ensure the valid syntax is being implemented into the Access Database**.  Steve posted a nice example, so I won't post code example.  But hopefully this helps you understand the differentiation between them.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't need full date and time, I just need date.
In the fist query I put date in field, in secound I need to compere where is date same in column and sifra is same. I use same string date, to insert date and then check date.