# UPDATE query not working with date field

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

`string date=
   DateTime.Now.ToString("d.M.yyyy",System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);`

```
String MyString = @"UPDATE cas SET Odhod= '" + label1.Text + "' 
WHERE sifra = " + textBox1.Text + " and Datum = "+date+"";
```

When I do this update without `Datum` (German for "date") it works, but with `Datum` it doesn't work. I'm connected to an Accesss database, and the type of the table field `Datum` is `Date/Time`.

**Here is the program:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/hx4zduvul8mh2uy/8.4.zip
**Pictre of problem:** http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/5189/errorbh.jpg

Comment: If you look Picture (http://http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/5189/errorbh.jpg)
you see there is missing las nubmer of date, if I make date string yyyy.M.d is also missing last one.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [working with access database update statment not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907389/working-with-access-database-update-statment-not-working) Please do not submit the same question an hour later with different tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a parametrized query. You will not have to worry about date formats and it will make your query SQL-injection-safe.

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydb.accdb";
string query = "UPDATE cas SET Odhod = ? WHERE sifra = ? AND Datum = ?";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(
       "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName)) {

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", label1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", date);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

missing some apostrophes?

```
String MyString = @"UPDATE cas SET Odhod= '" + label1.Text + "' 
WHERE sifra = " + textBox1.Text + " and Datum = '"+date+"'";
```

Comment: thank you, but still not working.
http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/4118/98394649.jpg